# i18n-js Property 't' does not exist on type 'typeof import'

Tags: typescript, react-native, i18n-js

I installed the i18n-js library in a react-native project, and I got a problem with typescript.

I use the library this way:

i18n.js

```
import i18n from 'i18n-js';

import en from './locales/en.json';
import es from './locales/es.json';

i18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
i18n.locale = 'en';
i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = {en, es};

export default i18n;
```

Auth.tsx

```
import i18n from '../../i18n';
...
Alert.alert(i18n.t('login.accountCreatedTitle'));
```

I got this annoying Typescript error:

[image]

How can i solve that?

Comment: Solved downgrading to i18n-js 3.8

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const i18n = require('i18n-js');` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).